# Evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{^n\text{C}_{r}}{n^r(r+4)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, binomial-coefficients

> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{^n\text{C}_{r}}{n^r(r+4)}$$

The answer is $6-2e$ according to WolframAlpha: 
[Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20n%20to%20inf%20sigma%20r%3D0%20to%20infintiy%20(nCr)%2F(n%5Er(r%2B4).)

I first thought it was the expansion of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$, but that r+4 in the denominator is causing problems

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk I'm not able to simplify the limit in the question

Comment: @Rick It's unfortunate you have got so many downvotes, but removing what you tried doesn't help! Are you just looking for a place to start? If not, what methods have you used to solve this question?

Comment: @TobyMak I really don't know where to start in simplifying this limit, putting $^n\text{C}_r$ as $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ makes it more complicated, it also isn't the expansion of any binomial expression,  I really don't know what to do here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1.** Notice that for each fixed $k \geq 0$, we have

$$ \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+4)}
= \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{n^k k! (k+4)}
= \frac{1}{k! (k+4)} \prod_{j=1}^{k} \left( 1 - \frac{j-1}{n} \right). $$

Now this increases in $n$ and converges to $\frac{1}{k!(k+4)}$ as $n \to \infty$. So by the monotone convergence theorem,

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+4)}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+4)}
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(k+4)}. $$

The last sum can be computed by writing

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(k+4)}
= \int_{0}^{1} x^3 e^x \, dx
= \left[ (x^3 - 3x^2 + 6x - 6) e^x \right]_{0}^{1}
= 6 - 2e. $$

**Method 2.** As in other answers, you find that

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+4)}
= n^4 \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}} t^3 (1 + t)^n \, dt
\stackrel{nt = u}{=} \int_{0}^{1} u^3 \left(1 + \frac{u}{n} \right)^n \, du. $$

Taking $n\to\infty$, it follows that $\left(1 + \frac{u}{n} \right)^n \to e^u$ and hence by the dominated convergence theorem (or by the monotone convergence theorem, upon proving that the integrands increase in $n$),

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{n^k (k+4)}
= \int_{0}^{1} u^3 e^u \, du
= 6 - 2e. $$

Alternatively, we can utilize the fact that the integrands converge uniformly, which can be proved either by brutal force or by Dini's theorem.

Comment: Thank you for answering, in your method-1, how did you get $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(k+4)}
= \int_{0}^{1} x^3 e^x \, dx$?

Comment: @Rick, This follows by realizing $\frac{1}{k+4} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{k+3} \, dx$. Plugging this and interchanging the order of integration and summation (which can be rigorously justified in many ways) together with the Taylor series  $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^k}{k!}$ gives the identity.

Comment: Wow, that's a really cool way to do it! Never thought of reciprocals like that before.

Answer (score 0):

Hints :

First show that if $S_n$ is your sum, then 
 $$S_n=n^4\int_0^{1/n}t^3(1+t)^n dt$$
 and compute the integral, using tfat you can find constants $a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3$ such that
 $$t^3=a_0+a_1(t+1)+a_2(t+1)^2+a_3(t+1)^3$$

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to compute:

$$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{^n\text{C}_{r}}{n^r(r+4)}.$$

This can be done in usual way:
$$
S_n=n^4\int_0^{1/n} dx \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{r}x^{r+3}=
n^4\int_0^{1/n}  x^3(1+x)^n\,dx\\
=n^4\left[ \frac{x^3(1+x)^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{3x^2(1+x)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}
+\frac{6x(1+x)^{n+3}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\frac{6(1+x)^{n+4}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)}\right]_0^{1/n}\\
=\frac{n(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{3n^2(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}
+\frac{6n^3(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+3}}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\frac{6n^4(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+4}-6n^4}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)},
$$
so that
$$
\lim_{n->\infty}S_n=e-3e+6e-(6e-6)=6-2e.
$$

Comment: How did you write Sn as that integral to 1/n ?